# How can I determine the specific wifi adapter in my laptop (without disassembling it)?

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, drivers

I have  a pavilion 17z-p100. I did a reinstall recently and when I tried to use a couple of freeware mac spoofers I didn't get too far (various crashes, and TMAC was working fine before reinstall). Finally, I ran across a youtube video showing a "locally administered mac address" setting under wifi adapter properties>advanced tab.

Trouble is, my "advanced" tab contains no such setting. Fair enough, says I. Off I go to track down the "official" wifi drivers for my system on the HP site. Which shows this;

[image]

Worse yet; the Broadcom package contains 7 different devices, none of which are signed.

Now, obviously I could keep cycling through various adapters until I strike it rich, but that is... suboptimal. Tomorrow I will of course reach out to HP support. This may or may not be productive. And I am aware that both windows networking and command-line ipconfig return a make/model for the adapter. But, if they fail to produce the soft mac address setting (which was working before) why in the world should I believe them?

Comment: have you considered asking the manufacturer?  also, if a driver is designed for a particular chipset and it works then that indicates that the wifi adaptor has that chipset, which tells you a lot, perhaps all you need to know, about what wifi adaptor it is.  And also, if you're not sure but you think it may be a or b or c, then you could install drivers for each. One time I called my laptop manufacturer and he said the adaptor was either 'a' or 'b', so I could install both drivers.

Comment: Another time I called them and they looked at the exact series number besides model number, and the sticker on the laptop whether it was intel or amd,  and based on that and what they knew about their laptops,  they could tell me which wifi adaptor it had.  I see you mention you'll ask the manufacturer tomorrow. That is a good idea and will save you a lot of time

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to identify the chipset manufacturer of your wireless card (or any device for that matter):

1. Go to Device Manager.  Right-click the adapter you want to identify and hit Properties.
2. From the peroperties window, click the Details tab, then select Hardware IDs from the property dropdown.
3. You will see a bunch of values that all say something like `PCI\VEN_xxxx&DEV_xxxx&SUBSYS_xxx...`.  Look at first the 4 digits after the `PCI\VEN_` part of the string.  That number is the vendor code.  (The `&DEV_` portion indicates the model, but in your case, you only have one choice for each vendor).
4. Go to [the PCI Database web site](http://www.pcidatabase.com) to look up the vendor code for the device.

`8086` is Intel
`14E4`, `1166`, and `0A5C` are Broadcom
`168C`, `1969` and `5143` are Qualcomm/Atheros
`10EC` and `1095` are SLI/Realtek

That will tell you which driver you need to download.  I would recommend if you have the Intel or Realtek cards that you get the driver from their respective web sites rather than HP's.  Laptop manufacturers are horrible about keeping their drivers updated.  Atheros and Broadcom do not publish their wireless drivers, so you'll have to get those from HP.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Boot to a live Linux DVD such as Knoppix.
Run the command

> lspci

It should output detailed information about all of the hardware it sees, one of which should be the wi-fi adapter.

Comment: Although this answer is correct, if the kernel doesn't have the proper firmware or this is a unique wireless device it may not give the appropriate information. The "average" user is not normally capable or understanding of stuff like this. I won't downvote because it's a legitimate answer, but not very practical for most users, and the OP stated that he was on Windows 8.1

Comment: OK fair enough.  I would point out though, that the name of this discussion forum is superuser, not newbieuser.  I'm not disparaging newbies at all, but I know that many professional technicians use this site as a reference, and I craft my answers in part to help them expand their toolbox of knowledge.